# python socket client does not send anything

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I'am trying to do an integration via HTTP socket. I'am using python to create the socket client and send data to a socket server created in C.

As you can see in the following images, the integration documentation gives an example in C that shows how I must send the data to the server:

Integration documentation example:

1- [define record / structure types for the message header and for each message format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAapX.png)

2- [Declare / Create a client socket object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kqce.png)

3- [Open the socket component in non blocking mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWVo.png)

4- [declare a variable of the data structure type relevant to the API function you wish to call – then fill it with the correct data (including header). Copy the structure data to a byte array and send it through the socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxD5H.png)

I've tried to do that using the ctypes module from python:

```
class SPMSifHdr(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('ui32Synch1', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('ui32Synch2', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('ui16Version', ctypes.c_uint16),
        ('ui32Cmd', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('ui32BodySize', ctypes.c_uint32)
    ]

class SPMSifRegisterMsg(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('hdr1', SPMSifHdr),
        ('szLisence', ctypes.c_char*20),
        ('szApplName', ctypes.c_char*20),
        ('nRet', ctypes.c_int)
    ]

body_len = ctypes.sizeof(SPMSifRegisterMsg)
header = SPMSifHdr(ui32Synch1=0x55555555, ui32Synch2=0xaaaaaaaa, ui16Version=1, ui32Cmd=1, ui32BodySize=body_len)
body = SPMSifRegisterMsg(hdr1=header, szLisence='12345', szApplName='MyPmsTest', nRet=1)

socket_connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# config is a dict with the socket server connection params
socket_connection.connect((config.get('ip'), int(config.get('port'))))

socket_connection.sendall(bytearray(body))
socket_connection.recv(1024)
```

When I call the socket recv function it never receive anything, so I have used a windows tool to check the data that I sent and as you can see in the next image it seems any data is sent:
[Socket sniff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBdD2.png)

I've tried to send even a simple "Hello! world" string and the result is always the same.

The socket connection is open. I know it because I can see how many connections are open from the server panel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that the SocketSniff program only shows the sent data if the server return a response. In it case the server did never return nothing because some bytes were missing.

I found it creating my own socket echo server and checking that the data I was sending were uncomplete.

Mystery solved. :D